# List comprehension with different depth dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two dictionaries with the following structure:

1. `Quantity[week][day][time]`
2. `Cost[day][time]`

The goal is to multiply over a list comprehension the quantity * cost and then sum it. The `Cost` is the same for all weeks, however, the quantity will vary from week to week. Before adding the week to the first dictionary I had the following:

```
sum([Cost[day][time]*Quantity[day][time] for day,time in zip(df,tf)])
```

And it works as intended.
Is there a way to achieve the same with list comprehension now that the `Quantity` dictionary has one more level?

### Edit

I want to have a different result for each week. It should be
`sum(week1)+sum(week2)+...+sum(weekn)`

Comment: if you have different weeks then you cannot have a single number as a result, but you need one result for each week, if that what you want?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, yes, I want a result for each week. I'll state that in the question.

Comment: Note that you do not need the _list comprehension_ around the generator expression at all. `sum()` can take a generator expression, resolve it and sum its elements which results in one pass over the iterator instead of two if you had a list comprehension

Comment: What are `df`  and `tf`? Please provide a [mre] with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a week variable like so:

```
[sum(cost[day][time]*q[week][day][time] for day,time in zip(df,tf)) for week in wf]
```

Here is an example with an output:

```
q = {'week1': {'day1': {'time1': 21, 
                        'time2': 30}, 
               'day2': {'time1': 21, 
                        'time2': 40}}, 
     'week2': {'day1': {'time1': 22, 
                        'time2': 9}, 
               'day2': {'time1': 23, 
                        'time2': 24}}}

cost = {'day1': {'time1': 21, 
                'time2': 24}, 
        'day2': {'time1': 22, 
                 'time2': 23}}

wf = ['week1', 'week2']
df = ['day1', 'day2']
tf = ['time1', 'time2']

output = [sum(cost[day][time]*q[week][day][time] for day,time in zip(df,tf)) for week in wf]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[1361, 1014]
```

The output is a list of the sum for each week so the 'week1' sum is 1361 and the 'week2' sum is 1014.